# Correct way of adding object inside an Array in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new in React, working on a beginner project about creating a receipt and adding ingredients to the receipt. Right now I have a problem updating receipts by adding new ingredients. Successfully logged receipts object with newly added ingredients to the console screen, but could not render it.

dummy data looks like this:

```js
const data = {
    receipts:[
        { 
            id: 1, 
            title: "Demo Title",
            body: "You have to add some ingredients",
            ingredients: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    title: "Salt"
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    title: 'Sugar',
                },
            ],
        },    
    ]
}
```

This is state :

```js
state = {
   receipts: data.receipts,
}
```

I am updating receipt with handleUpdateForm()

```js
handleUpdateForm =(attr)=>{
  this.updateReceipt(attr);
}

updateReceipt =(attr)=>{
    this.setState({
        receipts: this.state.receipts.map(r=>{
            return Object.assign({},r,{
                title: attr.title,
                body: attr.body,
                ingredients: attr.ingredients,
            })
        })
    })  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Inside handleAddIngredient() I am updating receipts by adding new ingredient.
I tried concat() method got no success, here I am using spread operator, again same thing happened

```js
handleAddIngredient =(ingTitle, receiptId)=>{
    const ingred = this.addIngredient(ingTitle)
    const receipts = this.state.receipts.map(receipt=>{
        if(receipt.id === receiptId){
            return Object.assign({},receipt,{
                ingredients: [...receipt.ingredients,ingred]
            })
        }else{
            return receipt
        }
    })
    this.setState({receipts})
}

addIngredient = (ingTitle)=>{
    return {
        id: this.generateId(),
        title: ingTitle,
    }
}

generateId = ()=>{
    return '_' + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9);
}

render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <Header />
            <ReceiptList 
                receipts={this.state.receipts}
                onFormUpdate={this.handleUpdateForm}
                onDeleteReceipt={this.handleDeleteReceipt}
                onAddIngredient={this.handleAddIngredient}
            />
            <ToggleReceipt 
                onFormSubmit={this.handleSubmitForm}
                onAddIngredient={this.handleAddIngredient}
            />
        </div>
    )
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem was in passing props into the component with "ingredients" in state,
**getDrivedStateFromProps** solved it.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.setState({ receipts: [ ...this.state.receipts, newReceipt ]})
```